# Is it possible to create XSD unique constraint based combination of element and node with multiple elements?

Tags: xml, xsd

Having the following xml code

```
<repository>
    <software id="1">
        <versions>
            <version>version1</version>
            <version>version2</version>
        <versions>
        <name>name1</name>
    </software>
    <software id="2">
        <versions>
            <version>version3</version>
        <versions>
        <name>name1</name>
    </software>
    <software id="3">
        <versions>
            <version>version3</version>
        <versions>
        <name>name1</name>
    </software>
</repository>
```

is it possible to create xsd constraint based on both names and versions nodes?
Software 1 and 2 are unique while software 2 and 3 are not unique.

Comment: What have you tried, how did it fail? Do you expect that constraint to work with an arbitrary number of `version` elements in the `versions` element?

Comment: I tried
<xs:element name="repository" type="repositoryType">
 <xs:unique name="testUnique">
   <xs:selector xpath="software"/>
   <xs:field xpath="versions"/>
   <xs:field xpath="name"/>
 </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
and it does not work because it seems it requires selector to match only element.
I expected arbitrary number of version elements but if it is not possible to match arbitrary number of them maybe it would be possible to match at least the first one. 
But I could not do this too. "<xs:field xpath="versions/version[1]"/>" did not work.

Comment: Yes, doing `versions/version[1]` isn't allowed by the restricted XPath subset the `field` `xpath` attribute supports. And selecting a complex type element like `versions` isn't allowed either. So as Michael Kay says in his answer, the way out of the dilemma, but only available with XSD version 1.1,  is to use assertions. Do you use an XSD 1.1 processor like recent Xerces or Saxon EE or are you stuck on XSD 1.0 (like e.g. Microsoft)?

Answer (score 0):

No, the XSD xs:unique mechanism requires a one-to-one correspondence between the fields used in the constraint.

You can do it, of course, using XSD 1.1 assertions - but since you've only given an example and not a specification, I'm not sure exactly what the assertion would be.

Answer (score 0):

Using an assertion in XSD 1.1 might work e.g.

```
   <xs:element name="repository">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="software"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert id="unique-versions-and-name"
              test="every $software in software
                   satisfies 
                     not(some $other-software in software[not(. is $software)] satisfies deep-equal($software/*, $other-software/*))"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

I have used the descriptive id `unique-versions-and-name` although technically later on, in XPath, I check simply for the same child elements with e.g. `deep-equal($software/*, $other-software/*)` so perhaps you rather want `deep-equal($software/(versions, name), $other-software/(versions, name))`.